# Problems using 2 ListFragment's within the same ListActivity

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I haven't added any code because this is more design related.

I’m new to android development. So, after going through an abundance of material, I’ve begun to design and develop my first app. Although I began using the Activity approach for phones, the platform changed right in the middle of my research (bummer!), leading me to add fragments to the mix. So, much of what I’ve been doing recently is with Activities and Fragments.

With this paradigm I’ve been running into problems all over the place, spending enormous amounts of time fixing things as I go along (I’m probably not the only one this has happened to).

But to get to the point: I backed into discovering that using multiple types of fragments within an Activity has limitations. I was trying to create more than one list on a tablet display, which has more real estate. As the examples show, I created a ListFragment.  Inside the onActivityCreated () method of the ListFragment, a list adapter is used to generate the initial list on the left side of the screen. I then tried to implement a SimpleCursorAdapter in another ListFragment, which I could never get to work. I tried researching the problem to see if anyone had a similar experience to no avail. So I tried adding the code for the SimpleCursorAdapter to the first ListFragment (commenting out all reference to the 2nd ListFragment) and, although it worked, it would override the 1st list, which was not what I wanted. I really wanted one list to appear on the left side of the screen, this next list to appear in the middle of the screen, and then a UI to pop up on the right side of the screen, loaded with information after selecting from the 2nd list. But since I could only generate the lists within the onActivityCreated() method of the 1st ListFragment (and the onActivityCreated() method is critical; it wouldn’t work from any other method), I was stuck with the 2nd list replacing the 1st list in the initial ListFragment.

When I attempted to use a 2nd ListFragment inside the containing FragmentActivity, using static classes (I don’t understand why there seems to be such a need to use static classes, but that’s another discussion), there was continual confusion with the system selecting the wrong onActivityCreated() method, which makes since because how does it know how to differentiate between the two methods in the different ListFragments. Since I don’t know the internals of Android at this point, I don’t know how to get around this problem.

I was thinking about using another model, Tabs across the action bar, with each Tab representing a different Activity, but I see that the TabActivity class is now deprecated, encouraging me to use TahHost, which I will begin researching.

The reason for the post is to try and reduce the amount of mistakes, pursuing the wrong path. So, has anyone had similar problems/challenges, and if so, how did you resolve them?

Any insights are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd say the quickest way to try and start this is to build two separate activities with separate lists. Once you have the two lists working independently save your progress (hopefully with a SCM) and then come back at making the lists work side by side. Without code, it is going to be difficult to suggest meaningful changes, but breaking your development up will make it easier for us to address the issues you are hitting specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a small test project that includes a situation similar to what you're looking for. It has two pages, the second page is a Fragment Activity that hosts two different ListFragments.

https://github.com/sababado/NavTest

I hope this will help.

Comment: Sababado, I don't see code with 2 fragments within a containing activity. I don't think this is what I need, but I appreciate your responding. I will look at further to see if I'm missing something. Again, thanks. Doug

Comment: Nick, thanks for your comment. What you're suggesting is the approach I'm now taking. I just thought there might be a way to continue with using a containing activity and then adding the static list fragment classes. But having more than one list per activity doesn't seem to work. Doug

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your question then. My code definitely shows two list fragments on one activity. They're my own custom type of list fragments (SearchableListFragment) however the base is still a list fragment.

Comment: Sababado, your use of 2 fragments is similar to what I am already doing. As I mentioned, I was trying to generate 2 separate lists using one list fragment. Since this didn't work, I was trying to use 2 list fragments, which wouldn't work in the same containing fragment activity. I see where you are animating 2 different areas of the screen, but my problem occurs when I try to extract data from a sqlite db into a 2nd list. The data appears, but it always replaces the first list. However, I noticed that you used some if conditions that may work. I'll take a closer look at your logic and try it.

Comment: Sababado, I'm drawing a blank on this. There has been some improvement, but I'm still not able to get things working as I want them. Thanks for your help, but I think I'm going to try another design approach, for I've spent way too much time on this.